# Events management using SDL 2.0

Tags: opengl, sdl

I wrote a simple SDL program using SDL 2.0. I have a little problem when I want to check the mouse wheel events. Actually, in the version 2.0 the flags SDL_BUTTON_WHEELDOWN and SDL_BUTTON_WHEELUP no longer exist. There is just the flags SDL_MOUSEWHEEL. The code below check correctly the' WHEELUP' and 'WHEELDOWN' events but with the same flag.

```
while(!terminer)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&evenements))
        {
            switch (evenements.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                terminer = true;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (evenements.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    terminer = true;
                    break;
                }
                break;
                case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                    std::cout << "MOUSE : MOVE" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    std::cout << "MOUSE : BUTTON DOWN" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:
                    std::cout << "MOUSE : WHEEL" << std::endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

But I would like to handle separately the 'WHEELUP' and 'WHEELDOWN' events. I tried several others flags in my condition but without success. Does anyone can help me, please ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the SDL documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseWheelEvent):

> Movements to the left generate negative x values and to the right
>   generate positive x values. Movements down (scroll backward) generate
>   negative y values and up (scroll forward) generate positive y values.

So in your case, you could modify the code as such:

```
case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:
    if(evenements.x < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "MOUSE : WHEEL LEFT" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(evenements.x > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "MOUSE : WHEEL RIGHT" << std::endl;
    }
    if(evenements.y < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "MOUSE : WHEEL DOWN" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(evenements.y > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "MOUSE : WHEEL UP" << std::endl;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Hello. I didn't talk about the mouse motion (when you move the mouse with the hand in all the direction represented by the SDL_MOUSEMOTION flag) but the wheel of the mouse (the wheel between the two button represented by the flag SDL_MOUSEWHEEL). I don't know how to separate the 'UP' event and the 'DOWN' event. Actually both are represented by SDL_MOUSEWHEEL flag.

Comment: Did you read the link? This is valid for the mouse wheel.

Comment: Ok sorry. As you say, in my example the 'wheel down' event is right for the condition if evenements.wheel.y < 0 and 'wheel down' is right if the condition evenements.wheel.y > 0 is respected. Thank you very much for your answer! Bye.